# TTransportException: Could not make HTTP Request- Evernote/iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, evernote

I am working on an iPad app that connects to Evernote to sync a user's notes to the app. Everything works great on my development devices and all of our internal testers, but there are several external testers that are having an issue after they authenticate with Evernote.  When the app goes to make a call to the API, it returns a

> TTransportException: Could not make HTTP Request.

Directly after calling `[evernoteSession.authenticateWithViewController]` successfully, I am calling `[evernoteSession.userStore getUserWithSuccess]`. This is where the user's are receiving the exception from evernote. Any ideas about why certain external testers would receive this error and not any of our internal testers or developers? Is there anything I can do to get more information about what is going wrong with the evernote API call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that they are on a cellular connection and they have authorised Evernote for mobile data but not your app?

In that case, I suspect they might be able to authenticate *within* Evernote but your app would then fail.

Note also that this issue has come up a few times on the Evernote forums, eg:

[Aug 2012](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/28758-ttransportexception-reason-bad-response-from-http-server-501-error/) problem was checking `authtoken == nil` in the connect method.

[Feb 2013](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/35181-get-ttransportexception-when-try-to-retrieve-note-info/) Problem was doing `getDefautNoteBook` or `listNotebooks` in UI thread, needed to be in a background thread (according to Evernote employee).

Comment: Thanks, Andy.  I will check those out.  I am now able to reproduce the problem by using the evernote app to authenticate.  When it returns to my app, I receive an error when connecting to the userStore.